# How should I represent a chess bitboard in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, chess

What are some of the possible ways of representing a chess bitboard in Clojure (/Java)?

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~psilord/blog/data/chess-pages/rep.html

I need to be able to access individual bits and also perform bitwise operations.

I thought of using java.lang.Long but this causes issues with 1x10^63 because of the signage. I'm also not sure how I would access bits at a specific index?

I also looked at BitSet, but I need a fixed length ideally.

Comment: 'the best way' - show your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/; 'How should I' - not constructive. What code do you have? What are your requirements? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @sehe I've tried using java.lang.Long but ran into problems with parseLong() and "10000...x63" - 1x10^63) Also, I'm not sure if I can access the bit at a specific index?
I'm asking for rationalised suggestions and ideas, not necessarily an absolute.

Comment: You should edit these details into your question.

Comment: this helps understanding bitmasks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29

Comment: `10^63`? That doesn't fit in a long...

Comment: @dbaupp Exactly, I was using parseLong on it's string with a radix of 2 to represent it, but this is my main issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use a straight long. The problem, as you've noted, is that java's (and therefore clojure's) long is signed, allowing only 63 bits for positive numbers

Java, by default, allows arithmetic overflow without error. Clojure, by default, doesn't allow arithmetic overflow without error (see [*unchecked-math*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2aunchecked-math%2a) flag). It adds extra checking around arithmetic operations and casts, so, for instance, `(byte 128)` will cause an exception. Since clojure v1.3.0 there are functions like `(unchecked-byte)` which is equivalent to the java functionality....

```
(unchecked-byte 128)
;=> -128 ; 2s-complement of 10000000
(unchecked-byte 2r10000001)
;=> -127 ; 2s-complement of 10000001
```

There are a whole raft of `unchecked-*` operations available ([see clojuredocs](http://clojuredocs.org/search?x=0&y=0&q=unchecked&lib=clojure_core)).

If you use a straight long and the `unchecked-*` operations you are mostly there, and then you can use the `bit-*` operations to twiddle/check bits.

Finally storing your chessboard in an atom makes sense, and you then update it with `(swap! chessboard fn args)`

**(updated 15/02/13 with slightly more idiomatic swap! calls)**

e.g.

```
(inc Long/MAX_VALUE) ; java.lang.ArithmeticException

(unchecked-inc Long/MAX_VALUE) ; wraps.
-9223372036854775808

(def chessboard (atom 0))
@chessboard
;=> 0
(bit-test @chessboard 1)
;=> false
(swap! chessboard bit-flip 1)
;=> 2
(bit-test @chessboard 1)
;=> true
@chessboard
;=> 2
(reset! chessboard 0)
;=> 0
(swap! chessboard bit-flip 63)
;=> -9223372036854775808 
(bit-test @chessboard 63)
;=> true
```

Comment: Hmmm, this should be in core but for some reason I'm getting:

`user=> (unchecked-byte 2r100101)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: unchecked-byte in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)`

Comment: I updated answer to note that unchecked-* appeared in clojure 1.3.0

Comment: +1 for great answer. Only thing I would add is that you may want to use Java primitive arrays of longs (since typically you want to manipulate many bitboards at the same time). If bitboard-crunching is going to be 90% of your CPU usage, it's worth using primitive arrays for the extra speed and space efficiency they will give you.

Answer (score 1):

```
=> (def chessboard (byte-array 8))
#'user/chessboard

=> (vec chessboard)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

=> (for [row (range 8)] (aset-byte chessboard row (rand-int 8)))
(3 0 6 6 2 3 6 7)

=> (bigint chessboard)
216179404987106823N

=> (defn bigint-to-array
 [bi]
 (.toByteArray (biginteger bi)))

=> (vec (bigint-to-array 216179404987106823N))
[3 0 6 6 2 3 6 7]
```

Clojure supports most functions you need this way. Like all clojure numbers, clojure.lang.BigInt supports binary operations (bit-and etc.). On a byte-array you can use all methods from [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) (search, fill, sort).

Take care that the bigint fn coerces to clojure.lang.BigInt, and the biginteger fn coerces to a java.math.BigInteger. If you want to use the methods of [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), you need to coerce your bigint or byte-array through biginteger.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how this would compare performance-wise against using long? I imagine it's slower.

Comment: Clojure bigints do not support bit operations.

user=> (bit-and (bigint 5) (bigint 3))
IllegalArgumentException bit operation not supported for: class clojure.lang.BigInt  clojure.lang.Numbers.bitOpsCast (Numbers.java:1008)